# Android Listview, on click get name of item in list

Tags: android, listview, android-studio

I have a listView with movies. When user clicks on a movie, i would like the name of that director to show up in the Toast.

The Toast is working. I am just not sure how to get the name.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if(convertView == null){
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, null);
            holder.ivMovieIcon = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);
            holder.tvMovie = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvMovie);
            holder.tvTagline = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTagline);
            holder.tvYear = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvYear);
            holder.tvDuration = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDuration);
            holder.tvDirector = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDirector);
            holder.rbMovieRating = (RatingBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.rbMovie);
            holder.tvCast = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvCast);
            holder.tvStory = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvStory);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Name of Director",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });


        final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(movieModelList.get(position).getImage(), holder.ivMovieIcon, new ImageLoadingListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        holder.tvMovie.setText(movieModelList.get(position).getMovie());
        holder.tvTagline.setText(movieModelList.get(position).getTagline());
        holder.tvYear.setText("Year: " + movieModelList.get(position).getYear());
        holder.tvDuration.setText("Duration: " + movieModelList.get(position).getDuration());
        holder.tvDirector.setText("Director: " + movieModelList.get(position).getDirector());

        // rating bar
        holder.rbMovieRating.setRating(movieModelList.get(position).getRating()/2);

        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        for(MovieModel.Cast cast : movieModelList.get(position).getCastList()){
            stringBuffer.append(cast.getName() + ", ");
        }

        holder.tvCast.setText("Cast:" + stringBuffer);
        holder.tvStory.setText(movieModelList.get(position).getStory());
        return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder{
        private ImageView ivMovieIcon;
        private TextView tvMovie;
        private TextView tvTagline;
        private TextView tvYear;
        private TextView tvDuration;
        private TextView tvDirector;
        private RatingBar rbMovieRating;
        private TextView tvCast;
        private TextView tvStory;
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not using `OnItemClickListener `?

Comment: just call `movieModelList.get(position).getDirector()`

Comment: I am still new to android development. Didn't think of using OnItemClickListener

Comment: Hi, i changed it to movieModelList.get(position).getDirector(). I also had to change public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent). to avoid error. Changing int position to final. Is that a good idea or bad idea

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is very simple.....

```
 convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, movieModelList.get(position).getDirector(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Hi i changed it to your example. I also had to change 
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) to avoid errors. Changing int position to final. Is that a good idea or bad idea.

Comment: @Kong this logic is perfect

Comment: @Kong nothing wrong in making final variable position

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your initial Listview variable
Maybe this can resolve your problem dude
[Listview with toast message on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18316925/listview-with-toast-message-on-click)

Answer (score 0):

You can check your Toast Now

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(final View v) {
   Toast.makeText(Context, "Name of Director"+movieModelList.getMethod(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

**EDIT**

```
  listViewObj.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // Toast
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Hope this helps you .